# How to export this node.js function in react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, puppeteer

i am working on a dashboard were the user should be able to click on a button and then get some data that would have been **scraped** from a site. I used puppeteer and it prints the desired data to the console but now how can i add this to my react js application ?

Here's the puppeteer code i wrote :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrapeProduct(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const [el] = await page.$x('/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a/img');
    const src = await el.getProperty('src');
    const srcTxt = await src.jsonValue();

    const [el2] = await page.$x('/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/a/h3');
    const txt = await el2.getProperty('textContent');
    const rawTxt = await txt.jsonValue();

    const [el3] = await page.$x('/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div');
    const txt2 = await el3.getProperty('textContent');
    const tags = await txt2.jsonValue();

    console.log({srcTxt, rawTxt, tags});
    browser.close();
}

scrapeProduct('https://2degrees-investing.org/resources/');
```

Is there a way to export this function and use it as an import somewhere ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Absolutely. Turn it into a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). Then, you can `import` it, and call `scrapeProduct()` within a `useEffect()` of a given component, and store the returned data in state, for example. Don't forget to return the data in `scrapeProduct()` instead of log it.

Comment: Okay i think i see the point. I am going to try this ! Thanks

Comment: You can't use puppeteer in react because it's backend only. You can make a request from react to an express script that launches puppeteer...